# Como usar abs() em uma função if, else if (c)

Tags: c

Edit 2: O que me foi pedido:

> O seu programa deve ler as coordenadas de uma bola de futebol sobre o campo, e dizer se ela está dentro do campo, se saiu pela lateral, se saiu pelo fundo ou se está dentro do gol. O campo é um retângulo de 100x70m. O centro das coordenadas está no centro do campo. As coordenadas x do campo vão de -50 a 50. O programa deve ler primeiro a coordenada x e depois a coordenada y da bola. Considere uma linha em diagonal saindo de cada canto do campo, para decidir se a bola saiu pela lateral ou pelo fundo. Considere o gol como um retangulo de 7,32 x 2,44m saindo de cada fim de campo, no meio dele. A única informação impressa pelo programa deve ser uma linha (terminada por \n), com uma das mensagens: "dentro", "lateral", "fundo" ou "gol".

Edit: Código completo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
//Vinicius Rossato Piovesan, Code::Blocks 17.12

int main()
{
float x, y, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h;
a=50;
b=-50;
c=35;
d=-35;
e=51.22;
f=-51.22;
g=3.66;
h=-3.66;
printf("Digite a coordenada de x (da bola): \n");
scanf("%f", &x);

printf("Digite a coordenada de y (da bola): \n");
scanf("%f", &y);

if(x<=a && x>=b &&  y<=c && y>=d)
printf("Dentro. \n");

else if (x>=a && x<=e && y>=h && y<=g || x<=b && x>=f && y<=g && y>=h)
printf("Gol. \n");

else if ((x>a || x<b) && (y<=c || y>=d))
printf("Fundo. \n");

else if (x-a >= y-c || x+b >= y+d)
printf("Fundo. \n");

else
printf("Lateral. \n");

return 0;
}
```

Boa noite.

Fiz um post mas ficou confuso, e infelizmente não consigo deletar.

Eu preciso fazer com que o número atribuído a X esteja em abs para que seja só positivo, mas não sei como atribuir.

```
  else if ((x>a || x<b) && y<=c && y>=d)
  printf("Fundo. \n");

  else if (x-a >= y-c || x+b >= y+d)
  printf("Fundo. \n");

  else
  printf("Lateral. \n");

  return 0;
  }
```

Grato.

Comment: converter o `x` para positivo, caso seja negativo? É isso?

Comment: Sim, seria isso.

Comment: Quando eu atribuo ao x -75 e ao y 50 (deveria dar o resultado de FUNDO), fica resultado de lateral, como se não lê-se algum dos números "direito"

Comment: Link da pergunta anterior: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/326300/132

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**abs(int x)**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_abs.htm)  esta função retorna o valor absoluto de x.

- Caso `x`negativo, retorna positivo.
- Caso `x` positivo, retorna positivo.

---

```
x=abs(x);   //basta esta linha para converter `x` para positivo

 else if ((x>a || x<b) && y<=c && y>=d)
  printf("Fundo. \n");

  else if (x-a >= y-c || x+b >= y+d)
  printf("Fundo. \n");

  else
  printf("Lateral. \n");

  return 0;
  }
```

Caso queira comparar os valores de forma absoluta, então teria de fazer as operações desta forma:

```
  else if (abs(x-a) >= abs(y-c) || abs(x+b) >= abs(y+d))
```

---

**Codigo relativamente ao enunciado:**

```
else if (x>=a && x<=e && y>=h && y<=g || x<=b && x>=f && y<=g && y>=h)
printf("Gol. \n");


else if(abs(x)-abs(y)>15)
printf("Fundo. \n");

else
printf("Lateral. \n");
```

Aquele `15` é a linha limite entre `fundo` e `lateral`, exemplo:

- `(51-35)= 16`, está no *fundo*
- `(51-37)= 14`, está na *lateral*

É um pouco complicado explicar aquele numero mágico, o `15`, mas é como se fosse a equação da reta, com inclinação 15

Comment: Ok, tentei aplica-los no código mas ainda assim na hora de compila-lo os resultados não batem.
Poderia verificar o que há de errado?
Eu preciso dar duas coordenadas, e quando elas vão por escanteio devo dizer se foram para o fundo ou lateral. Consegui fazer usando positivo, mas quando devo usar negativo os resultados não batem.

Comment: @vinicius está uma confusão de todo o tamanho, eu não estou a par do problema, eu não sei o que é o fundo ou lateral

Comment: Foi me pedido para ler as coordenadas de uma bola de futebol sobre o campo, e dizer se ela está dentro do campo, se saiu pela lateral, se saiu pelo fundo ou se está dentro do gol. O campo é um retângulo de 100x70m. O programa deve ler primeiro a coordenada x e depois a coordenada y da bola. As coordenadas x do campo vão de -50 a 50. Considere uma linha em diagonal saindo de cada canto do campo, para decidir se a bola saiu pela lateral ou pelo fundo. E é isso que eu tento fazer desde então.

Comment: Ou vamos simplificar, há como colocar a função abs dentro do else if, visto que se eu colocar o x=abs(x) acima do else if eu não poderei usar else if, e sim if.

Comment: Diga 1 exemplo de uma coordenada que é considerado fundo e 1 que seja considerada lateral. Eu fiz esse exemplo, é o ultimo codigo que eu coloquei, tem o `abs` dentro do `if`

Comment: Uma coordenada fundo (x) é uma que seja maior que a (50), e esteja, ou não, acompanhado de uma coordenada y. Calcula-se a diferença da coordenada x e y para saber se é fundo ou lateral assim:
x= x-50
y= x-35

Ditei o x como 100 e y como 60
x=100-50 = 50
y=60-35 = 25

O x é maior que o y, logo é fundo.
Se y-35>x-50 então é lateral.

O problema acontece quando eu uso números negativos, porque dai

y= -60
x= -100 o x é > que y, será que por ser negativo devo usar <?

x=-100-50 = 50
y=-60-35 = 25

Comment: Eu queria um exemplo, algo como `(50,0)` essa coordenada está na linha no fim do campo do lado direito, `(50,-35)` está no canto inferior direito do campo. Quero saber o que é considerado `fundo` com uma coordenada de exemplo. No meio desse texto todo é impossivel tentar ajudar, porque está super confuso.

Comment: Uma coordenada fundo é x(70) y(50). Uma coordenada lateral é x(60) y(80).

Comment: Isso não faz sentido, o centro do campo tem coordenada `(0,0)`, essas 2 coordenadas que deu de exemplo estão ambas fora do campo. `(50, 35)` está no canto superior direito do campo, `50, -35` está no canto inferior direito. Edite a resposta, meta uma imagem de um campo e identifique a região do `fundo` e `lateral`, a maneira que está explicando é impossível ajudarmos

Comment: Publiquei uma resposta com imagem.

Comment: Vou editar a minha resposta, penso que já tenha a solução

Comment: Muito obrigado!
Deu certo, agora vou re-ler o que você escreveu até entender a lógica por trás disso.
Novamente, muito obrigado.

Comment: @vinicius Caso não tenha restado duvidas seleccione esta resposta como correta, carregando no "certinho" ✅